# reduce integers if covering 0-9

Tags: c#, algorithm, compression

what can be the best solution to do the following to an array of integers (may be better to treat them as strings) in c# :

**Example 1:**

Array consists of :

```
440 - 441 - 442 - 443 - 444 - 445 - 446 - 447 - 448 - 449 - 51 - 9876
```

result should be :

```
44 - 51 - 9876
```

applied rule 441 to 449 replaced with 44 because we have the complete set of 0 - 9

**Example 2**

Array consists of :

```
440 - 441 - 442 - 443 - 444 - 445 - 446 - 447 - 448 - 449 - 40 - 41 - 42 - 43 - 45 - 46 - 47 - 48 - 49
```

result should be :

```
4 - 51 - 9876
```

applied rule : first the 3 character strings (all those starting with 44) reduced to 44 and then same rule reduces the 40 to 49 to 4.

Comment: 2 spaces and then newline  
for markdown newline

Comment: sort your list, parse for consecutive numbers, collapse, rinse and repeat until no more changes are found.

Comment: Copy/Paste is a real evil, look at the expected result for example 2

Comment: From his logic, the second example works as well. 440..449 collapses to 44, which completes the 40..43, 45..49 to 40..49 which collapses to 4

Comment: In your first example, how do you know `51` doesn't represent `50, 51, ..., 59` or even `500, 501, ..., 599`?

Comment: @Rawling 51 cannot represent 50,51,...,59 or 500, 501, ... . it presents 510 to 519

Comment: Of course, my mistake. What I meant was, how do youk now `51` doesn't represent `510, 511, ..., 519` i.e. how can you tell between a number that was on its own and a number that resulted from collapsing a series? (@SamIam I did _not_ know that!)

Comment: Fair enough. I'm just worried what will happen if you ever try to decompress it :)

Comment: @Rawling: it doesn't matter !! this is exactly what is intended ! but at this stage I need to compress the list.

Comment: @Rawling : I don't need to decompress this list, basically it will be used for matching incoming integers (strings) to this list. so for example if I recieve 449999 it will go under 44.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about being lazy and just using LINQ?

```
int[] arr1 = { 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 51, 9876 };

// This is just one reduction step, you would need loop over it until
// no more reduction is possible.
var r = arr1.GroupBy(g => g / 10).
        SelectMany(s => s.Count() == 10 ? new int[] {s.Key} : s.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: I am using a LINQ solution (slightly different) but not sure about the performance !

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses a sorted data structure but saves some sorting

Pseudo code:

```
numbers //your array of number
sortedSet //a sorted data structure initially empty

function insertSorted (number) {
  sortedSet.put(number) //simply add the number into a sorted structure
  prefix = number / 10 //prefix should be int to truncate the number

  for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    if ( ! sortedSet contains (prefix * 10 + i) )
      break; //so i != 10, not all 0-9 occurrences of a prefix found
  }
  if ( i== 10 ) {//all occurrences of a prefix found
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
      sortedSet remove (prefix*10 + i)
    }
    insertSorted(prefix) //recursively check if the new insertion triggered further collapses
  }
}
```

Finally I would call in this way:

```
foreach number in numbers
  insertSorted (number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a ten-branch index tree, record the number of children of each node.
Then browse the tree, stop at the node whose child number is ten.